# Time Based Authentication

Tags: authentication, one-time-password

I need a way of authenticating that a file was generated by a particular machine that has a unique ID and a unique random secret also known to the authenticator, as an added difficulty the file producer cannot directly communicate with the authentication machine. My current methodology is as follows:

File gen:

1. File Producer passes time and secret to a non-reversible hashing algorithm and exports that

`{
   id: 1337,
   time: 1435102405,
   oneTimekey: 99754106633f94d350db34d548d6091a,
   ...
}`

File Authenticity Check:

1. If the time specified in the file is within arbitrary bounds and a secret associated with the ID is found continue otherwise fail
2. Passes time and secret to a non-reversible hashing algorithm if it matches the oneTimeKey then it is assume to be valid.

In this methodology I have to store the secret in a database, I would prefer not to do this but I can't think of an effective way to achieve this goal any other way. Have I looked over something? Can I achieve this without storing the secret on the authentication side?

Comment: Would a [TOTP - RFC6238](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238) implementation satisfy your need well enough?

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords the more I think about this RSA signing of the file is a far better method than ether my crude idea or TOTP - RFC6238. Not sure why I didn't think of that first.

Comment: If all you're doing is validating that in a local-tamper-resistant manner, then yes, a public-private signature where the signing devices have unique private keys would seem reasonable.  You can sign a timestamp, if you like to know about timing :).